# Custom Memberpress registration page not showing payment gateways

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I have created a custom template for use on a member press membership including the shortcode `[mepr-membership-registration-form id="123"]`.

I have a stripe payment test gateway setup, however the registration form does not proceed to payment with a custom template enabled.

Disabling the custom template in the membership does show the card entry form however and allows me to finish the registration.

**Question:**

Is there another shortcode/url I am missing for the registration form to show the gateways?

Comment: Bumping this topic since I am having the same issues. The shortcode will actually work only if we are on the memberpress (membership) page.

Comment: Looks like if you are calling the ``[mepr-membership-registration-form id="xx"]`` witin an other shortcode it won't wok.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the show/hide feature on the custom field to make it show to the user.

If you want choose which fields show for specific memberships, you have to select "Customize User Information Fields" box under the Membership Options tab in Memberpress > Memberships > Your Membership Name.